# Как высчитать из месяцев года и месяца для отображения?

Tags: javascript

Как высчитать из месяцев года и месяца для отображения?
Еще бы как сделать так что бы 1 год 2 года и тд после 5ти идет 5лет!
Опять же 24 года... эти слова лет и год года как правильно выводить?

Comment: В заголовке и тексте разные вопросы.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну, так-то тут 2 вопроса... ТС, не смешите.. делите кол-во заданных месяцев на кол-во месяцев в году (и будет целое вашими годами), с остатком, надеюсь, самит справитесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
function morph(int, array) {
    return array[(int % 100 > 4 && int % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(int % 10 < 5) ? int % 10 : 5]];
}
console.log(morph(5,['год','года','лет'])); // лет
```