# Как из числа месяцев получить количество лет и остаток месяцев?

Tags: javascript

Как из целого числа месяцев получить количество лет и остаток месяцев?

*Пример*: 14 месяцев = 1 год и 2 месяца.

Comment: если кто-то понял суть вопроса, скажите: это не [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992670/178576)?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Судя по заголовку дубликат, судя по содержанию, разные вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let months = 7;
let resultYears = Math.floor(months / 12);
let resultMonths = months % 12;
```

Делаем два разных деления.

Comment: parseInt здесь совершенно лишнее

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, в resultMonths оно не нужно, однако в resultYears без него никак.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо, изменил.

Comment: стой а буде ли вычисляться года из месяцев ? что бы потом остаточные месяца показать

Comment: @anuarthor Извените, не очень вас понял. В переменной months ваше входное значение месяцев. В переменных resultYears и resultMonths полное количество лет и остаточное количество месяцев соответствено.